strain energy in thermomechanics problem
In continuum mechanics, the strain energy is calculated as
$\int_\Omega \boldsymbol{\varepsilon} : \boldsymbol{\sigma} dV$
in which $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon} = \nabla^s \mathbf{u}$ is the strain and $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ is the stress.
When the thermal strain is taken into account, the total strain becomes
$\boldsymbol{\varepsilon} = \nabla^s \mathbf{u} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_T$
The question is whether the new strain energy is calculated as
$\int_\Omega \nabla^s \mathbf{u} : \boldsymbol{\sigma} dV$
or
$\int_\Omega \left( \nabla^s \mathbf{u} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_T \right) : \boldsymbol{\sigma} dV$
?
IMO, the first variant shall be used since the thermal strain is induced by temperature and shall impose no contribution to strain energy.

How is the stress defined in that case? I always assumed that thermal changes affect the stress, i.e., they go into $\sigma$ via $\sigma = C\nabla^s u + p_TI$ where $p_T$ is the pressure due to thermal expansion/contraction.

@WolfgangBangerth the stress relates to the strain via the constitutive law, $\boldsymbol{\sigma} = \boldsymbol{\sigma} \left( \nabla^s \mathbf{u} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_T \right)$

The strain energy is basically the work done by the stresses in deforming the body
so your intuition about how to calculate it is correct. That also implies that no
strain energy is created if a body is allowed to freely expand, for example.
However, I think there is a better way to think about thermal and mechanical strains than
your second equation. Normally, the displacements of the body are assumed
to the total of all displacements produced by applied forces, temperature changes, etc.
These displacements are what you would measure if you went into the laboratory. So we would
subtract the so-called thermal strains from the strains calculated from the total
displacements. Strain measures are really just arbitrary quantities invented for convenience
in various constitutive relations.
$$\bf \epsilon_m =  \nabla u - \epsilon_T$$
where $\epsilon_m$ is a "mechanical strain" that is used in the appropriate constitutive law to compute the
stresses and the strain energy (e.g. Hooke's Law).
The end result is the same as you show but I find the above a more intuitive way to think about this.
